# Исчезает индикатор загрузки

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть первый «tableViewController» и второй «tableViewController». Если я нажимаю на ячейку в первом контроллере, я перехожу во второй. Если нажму на ячейку во втором контроллере, то начнется загрузка файлов и появляется индикатор загрузки.

Проблема: когда загрузка начинается, и я перехожу из второго контроллера к первому контроллеру и потом возвращаюсь ко второму контроллеру, мой индикатор загрузки исчезает. Как это исправить?

второй `tableViewController`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let url = URL(string: "link")!
    let downloadTaskLocal = self.backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: url)
    downloadTaskLocal.resume()

    let progressView = LCProgressView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(43), height: CGFloat(43)))
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell?.accessoryView = progressView
    progressView.start()
}
```

первый `tableViewController`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if (segue.destination is SecondViewController) {
        if let button = sender as? UIButton {
            (segue.destination as? SecondViewController)?.buttonIndex = button.tag
        }
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPyoC.png

Comment: Где этот индикатор? Приведите пример кода, уточните где проблема.

Comment: Как реализован переход между контроллерами?

Comment: Как загружаете? Второй контроллер при возврате уничтожается? А что с загрузкой происходит?

Comment: В ответе дали решение. Проверяйте идет ли загрузка и если да, то отображайте индикатор

Answer (score -5):

У вас код на добавление ячейки есть только в методе, исполняемом по нажатию на ячейку. Иначе говоря, пока пользователь не нажмет, индикатор не появится. Когда вы переходите на предыдущий экран и возвращаетесь снова назад, вам необходимо сохранить в модели, что происходит загрузка элемента, и индикатор добавлять не в `tableView:didSelectRowAt:`, а в `tableView:cellForRowAt:`.

Сохранить можно по-разному, можно добавлять к данным флаг типа `isDownloading`, или хранить таски загрузки в словаре с ключом типа `NSIndexPath`. Сделайте так, как будет наиболее эффективно в случае вашей конкретной модели данных.

Проблемы **UPD 1**:

- `viewDidAppear:`, `viewWillAppear` *должен* звать метод суперкласса, иначе возникают непредсказуемые баги
- вы в итоге так и не исправили, то что я описал в самом начале ответа -
  логика, описанная в `tableView:didSelectRowAt:` неверна. Проблемы две: во-первых, если данные станут динамическими, обращаться напрямую к ячейкам и к конкретной строке станет нельзя. Во-вторых, при переходе на предыдущий экран и возвращении на текущий весь контроллер пересоздастся заново и захваченные замыканием переменные хоть и не погибнут, но будут указывать не невалидные данные.

Comment: Тут еще же нюансы при обычном поведении `UINavigationController`, что при возврате на первый контроллер второй уничтожится.

Comment: @user обновил ответ.

Comment: @user обновил ответ.